# Show that $ X_t = \begin{cases} W_t & \text{if $t \neq a$ } \\ 0 & \text{if $t = a$ } \end{cases} $ is not a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion and $a \in (0,T)$. Consider the function $$ X_t = 
\begin{cases}
W_t  & \text{if $t \neq a$ } \\
0 & \text{if $t = a$ }
\end{cases}
$$

Show that $X_t$ is not a Brownian motion.

Here is my work:
I want to prove that the increments of $X_t$ are correlated.
Let $s<a<t$, $Cov(X_a - X_s, X_t-X_a) = Cov(-W_s,W_t) = -s$. Hence, the increments are not independent and $X_t$ is not a Brownian motion.

I'm not sure if I prove it right as I just picked one special case.

Comment: I think that you made it very good :-)

Comment: You can also note that $X_t$ is almost surely discontinuous (at $a$).  It's more fun if you replace the fixed time $a$ with a random time, say uniformly distributed on $[0,T]$.  Then the resulting process has all the right finite-dimensional distributions and does have independent increments, but still isn't a Brownian motion by the continuity argument.

Answer (score 2):

We need 
$$
X_a \sim \mathcal{N}(0,a)
$$
which is not the case.